# How can I place some text before the input form in admin site?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

How can I place some text, for example the user id, before the text input? I need something like this

[image: mockup]

code is a DecimalField

should I create a totally new widget?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to customize both your `ModelAdmin` class and form widget, like

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class ModelAdminFoo(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
         request = kwargs['request']
         if db_field.name == 'code':
             # You could put following customized widget elsewhere
             class Widget(forms.TextInput):
                 def render(self, *args, **kwargs):
                     return mark_safe('%d - ' % request.user.pk) + super(Widget, self).render(*args, **kwargs)
             kwargs['widget']= Widget()
         return super(ModelAdminFoo, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```